# Linq groupby with joining table

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Let's suppose there is a database to manage students.
I'm using the following (simplified) classes:

> **Student**
>
>  int id
>
>  string name

> **StudentEnrollmentInfo**
>
>  int studentId
>
>  int courseId

> **Course**
>
> int courseInfo
>
> string name

In the aforementioned tables, studentenrollmentinfo is a joining table, to handle the many to many relation between courses and students.

Now I'd like to query the names of all students who are currently enrolled in a list of different courses. For example:
Get all students enrolled in Biology, Maths and Arts, I'd like to get all students that are enrolled in ALL of those classes.

I have tried the following:

```
List<string> requiredCourses = new List<string>(){"Maths", "Biology", "Arts"}; 

var query = from student in _context.students
join enrollmentInfo in _context.StudentEnrollmentInfo on 
    student.id equals enrollmentInfo.studentId
join course in _context.Course on course.id equals enrollmentInfo.courseId
where requiredCourses.All(r => r.equals(course.name))
select(student.name)
```

This however does not work, my guess is because the joins, in addition to the joining table flattens the list, making it where every student with every course combination is a unique value, making it so that there is never any AND condition that is true.

Can anyone suggest something to point me in the right direction?

Comment: [Don’t use Linq’s Join. Navigate!](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/)

Answer (score 0):

```cs
List requiredCourses = new List() { "Maths", "Biology", "Arts" };
var query = (from student in _context.students
            join enrollmentInfo in _context.StudentEnrollmentInfo on student.id equals enrollmentInfo.studentId
            join course in _context.Course on course.id equals enrollmentInfo.courseId
            where **requiredCourses.Contains(course.name)**
            select student.name).Distinct().ToList()
```

hope it will solve your purpose. distinct will help for your unique data